# how to create log files in Gradle

Tags: gradle, ant

I am using Gradle-2.11 and I am unable to find a way to create log files that logs debug level information. I don't want to do it through command line by redirecting the logs to the log file. I want Gradle code just like Apache Ant's 'record' task so that I can put that code in my build.gradle file wherever I want to create logs.

For ex: If I want to convert this ant task to gradle, then what would be the code:

```
<record name="${BuildLogPath}/${BuildLogFile}" append="no" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
```

Comment: I don't believe Gradle supports this at the moment. I'm sure it can be done, though, so hopefully someone will provide an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Gradle integrates really nicely with Ant (https://docs.gradle.org/2.11/userguide/ant.html)

It doesn't automatically record each step. I didn't realize that is what you were asking. The updated below will produce the output and you can manually log.

```
ant.record(name: "${BuildLogPath}/${BuildLogFile}", append:false, loglevel: "verbose", action: "start")
ant.echo("start logging")

//... do stuff here

 ant.echo(message: "end logging")
 ant.record(name: "${BuildLogPath}/${BuildLogFile}", append:false, loglevel: "verbose", action: "stop")
```

This may do more of what you are asking. Note: This is something I adapted slightly from this excellent example:
  http://themrsion.blogspot.com/2013/10/gradle-logging-writing-to-log-to-file.html

```
import org.gradle.logging.internal.*
String currentDate = new Date().format('yyyy-MMM-dd_HH-mm-ss-S')
String loggingDirectory = "${rootDir}/build/logs"
mkdir("${loggingDirectory}")
File gradleBuildLog = new File("${loggingDirectory}/${currentDate}_gradleBuild.log")

gradle.services.get(LoggingOutputInternal).addStandardOutputListener (new StandardOutputListener () {
    void onOutput(CharSequence output) {
        gradleBuildLog << output
    }
})

gradle.services.get(LoggingOutputInternal).addStandardErrorListener (new StandardOutputListener () {
    void onOutput(CharSequence output) {
        gradleBuildLog << output
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am actually migrating the current Ant code to Gradle so again using Ant is not a good option for me.

Comment: Besides, this method is creating the log file but it is empty. Am I missing something?